# Why json can be imported easily where as csv cannot in Nodejs Typescript javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I was trying to import data from csv file. I tried the following statement:

```
import * as c from './t.csv';
```

I got the error:

> TypeScript error: src/dataset.ts(18,20): Error TS2307: Cannot find module './training.csv'.

Then I converted the file into a json file and tried the following code:

```
import * as c from './t.json';
```

It worked.
I wonder why the csv file was not loaded where as json file loaded without any issues.

Comment: Because JSON is Javascript for all intents and purposes, and CSV is a bunch of text you can't simply import…?

Comment: Also, this is not really a TypeScript issue, "normal" Node would error as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because [Any JSON text is a valid JavaScript expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#JavaScript_and_JSON_differences) and CSV is absolutely not.